# What is the need of an invisible affix?

Tags: linguistics, morphology, derivational-morphology, affixes

When nothing means something:

> In morpheme-based morphology, a **null morpheme** is a morpheme that is realized by a phonologically null affix (an empty string of phonological segments). In simpler terms, a null morpheme is an "invisible" affix. [*[Wikipedia]*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme)

*Wikipedia* says that examples in English include *hiatus* and *co-operation*. I didn't quite get how they have null morphemes. (Well, it is invisible, how am I supposed to see?)

I know that *hiatus* is the slight pause between two vowels coming together but not in the same syllable. *Hiatus* itself contains hiatus also. So, is that slight pause a null morpheme? But why do we need to explain with a null morpheme?

Another odd example in English is the invisible notion of singularity and plurality:

- *sheep* = sheep + -Ø = ROOT ("sheep") + SINGULAR
- *sheep* = *sheep* + -Ø = ROOT ("sheep") + PLURAL

I know that the plural form *sheep* was leveled with the singular in Old English. But why is the need of null morpheme here?

Can you please shed a light on this? Also, is *null morpheme* a well-accepted concept?

Comment: Interesting question, probably more for the *linguistic* site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia examples are not relevant. They are examples of insertion of a glide to prevent two vowels from being adjacent: specifically, a /j/ in *hiatus* and a /w/ in *co-operation*. That doesn't have anything to do with null morphemes.

As for the main question, "is null morpheme a well-accepted concept?", yes, it is, but it depends on your theory of inflectional morphology.

In *incremental* theories of morphology, inflectional morphology is information-increasing: each morpheme adds features to the stem. In this kind of approach, the feature PLURAL could be seen as the function of a morpheme added to a stem that is unspecified for number. For many words, the morpheme is realized as /s/ or /z/, e.g. *cats*, *dogs*. For others, the "morpheme" is some kind of floating vowel quality effect, as in *mouse* ~ *mice*. For examples like sheep, the morpheme is phonologically null. This is a necessary step if you believe that plurality can only be the result of adding a morpheme.

In *realizational* theories of morphology, on the other hand, lexical stems themselves are associated with a set of morphosyntactic features, which license the addition of certain affixes. In this kind of approach, there's no need for a phonologically null morpheme (though you could have one if you wanted).

Most popular theories of inflectional morphology these days are realizational rather than incremental, e.g. Distributed Morphology, A-morphous Morphology, Paradigm Function Morphology. Hope that helps, and let me know if anything needs clarification!